# JavaFX get corner coordinates of rotated imageView?

Tags: java, javafx, rotation, line

I am making a simple simulation, and have had a good amount of trouble finding the X and Y coordinates of a rotated, weirdly sized, imageView node. (The blue bit is the front)

[image: robot.png]

The goal is to find out an XY coordinate relative to the direction that the imageView is pointing, after it has been rotated. I can find the angle that the imageView is at relative to its starting position but I cannot figure out how to get an XY coordinate of the imageView relative to this angle. Since the .setRotate(angle) method does not change the X and Y location of the imageView, how should I go about finding a point that the imageView is facing?

Minimal example of the rotation and imageView I am using:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));

        Image robotImage = null;

        try {
            robotImage = new Image(new FileInputStream("res\\robot.png"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ImageView robot = new ImageView(robotImage);
        robot.setLayoutX(125);
        robot.setLayoutY(125);

        System.out.println("PreRotate X: " + robot.getLayoutX() + "PreRotate Y: " + robot.getLayoutY());
        robot.setRotate(45);
        System.out.println("PostRotate X: " + robot.getLayoutX() + "PostRotate Y: " + robot.getLayoutY());
        root.getChildren().add(robot);

        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I have already tried using the bounds of the imageView along with lines that lay on top of the imageView, but that requires me to find the new max/min x/y every time that the imageView changes its max/min x/y.

For example:

```
        if (turnAngle < 35) {
            directionLine.setStartX(robotLeftRightAngle.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX());
            directionLine.setStartY(robotLeftRightAngle.getBoundsInParent().getMinY());
            directionLine.setEndX(robotRightLeftAngle.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() + ((robotLeftRightAngle.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX() - robotRightLeftAngle.getBoundsInParent().getMinX()) / 2));
            directionLine.setEndY(robotRightLeftAngle.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() + ((robotLeftRightAngle.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() - robotRightLeftAngle.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()) / 2));
        }
        else if (turnAngle < 55) {
            directionLine.setStartX(robotLeftRightAngle.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX());
            directionLine.setStartY(robotLeftRightAngle.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY());
            directionLine.setEndX(robotRightLeftAngle.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() + ((robotLeftRightAngle.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX() - robotRightLeftAngle.getBoundsInParent().getMinX()) / 2));
            directionLine.setEndY(robotRightLeftAngle.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() + ((robotLeftRightAngle.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY() - robotRightLeftAngle.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()) / 2));
        }
```

[image: Yikes]

And so on all the way to 360. DRY yikes.

How should I approach this? Am I using the wrong transformation? Did I not see a method that can be used for this? I know that there must be a better approach. Thanks for reading.

Comment: The direction is based on the start position. If the angle is zero, it's pointing toward the original start position. if 90, it's pointing right of start direction. 180 is pointing opposite the original position. 270 is left of original position. You can use mod to stay at 360 and less. Negative values go left and end right.

Comment: @Sedrick Yes I already got the angle that the imageView is at, although I want to get a XY coordinate relative to the direction that the imageView is facing. I will make that more clear in the question thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I 100% understand the question. The transformations between coordinate systems but it's hard to tell the coordinate systems you need to convert between from your description, so I assume you want to convert between the coordinate system of `robot` to the coordinate system of `group`.

It's possible to use `localToParent` to convert from the coordinate system of a node to that of the parent which accomodates for all transforms. (`parentToLocal` would achieve the inverse transformation, but this does not seem to be the required transformation in this case.)

The following example modifies the start and end points of a line to the coordinates of the top left and a point 100 px above of the `Rectangle` in the `Rectangle`'s coordinate system:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Group root = new Group();

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));

    Rectangle robot = new Rectangle(100, 20, Color.RED);
    robot.setLayoutX(125);
    robot.setLayoutY(125);
    Line line = new Line(125, 125, 125, 25);

    robot.rotateProperty().addListener(o -> {
        Point2D start = robot.localToParent(0, 0);
        Point2D end = robot.localToParent(0, -100);
        line.setStartX(start.getX());
        line.setStartY(start.getY());
        line.setEndX(end.getX());
        line.setEndY(end.getY());
    });

    RotateTransition rotateTransition = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(5), robot);
    rotateTransition.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    rotateTransition.setFromAngle(0);
    rotateTransition.setToAngle(360);
    rotateTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    rotateTransition.play();

    root.getChildren().addAll(robot, line);

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation, but yes this was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!